# Apache Cordova windows run error MSBuild v4.0 not suported

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to use Apache Cordova for create applications for desktop Windows 10 and Android. It works fine on Android installing android studio, but I'm having problems on windows run or build.

I have Visual Studio Community edition 2019 installed. I didn't know which version I had to install for this case, so I installed .net for web pack and universal desktop pack (I don't know really if I did the correct instalation). When I use the command `cordova requirements` I have all of the requirements ok. But when I try to run the app in windows I have the error:

> MSBuild v4.0 is not supported, aborting.

Do I need to install a fever version? where can I get that version in that case? Do I need to install any more stuff or different one? I couldn't find any info about this instalation with Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to generate an [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) build from Cordova to build your desktop version of your application. Electron is a lot more mature than the Windows platform of Cordova.

Comment: That's very good advice.  Two additional links: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/electron/ and https://www.codemag.com/Article/1603041/Write-Cross-Platform-Apps-using-Electron

Comment: Lots of thanks I Though that electron where for mobile only. So thanks I will try with that.